# How can I read a certain amount of Bytes into a Buffer?

Tags: java, performance, buffer, nio, channel

The following problem: I have a large textfile with each line containing 13 bytes. I do not want to read the file line by line in the common way using InputStream. I am trying to use NIO Channels and MappedByteBuffers for better performance and limited rescources.

So this is what I do so far:

```
RandomAccessFile data = new RandomAccessFile("the_file.txt", "rw");
FileChannel channel = data.getChannel();
MappedByteBuffer buffer = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, capacity);
```

Here *capacity* is n*13, to make sure only whole lines fit into the Buffer.
But this does not work! I fill the Buffer like this:

```
int bytesRead = channel.read(buffer);
```

But that does not fill the complete Buffer! *bytesRead* does not equal *capacity*, and even worse in my case *bytesRead%13* is not *zero*, which means it does not contain whole lines, in the end something is cut off. **How can I read a certain amount of Bytes into the Buffer?** In my case I need exactly n*13 Bytes so that the original lines dont get split...

Comment: What value does `bytesRead` have? Perhaps you're hitting the OS preferring to do IO in page-sized chunks...

Comment: You can try `while(buffer.remaining() > 0) channel.read(buffer);`

Answer (score 2):

Taking a quick look at the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html#read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) reveals the truth about the `read` method.

> A read operation might not fill the buffer, and in fact it might not
>   read any bytes at all.

From this it should be pretty clear that it cannot be assumed that the `read` call will fill the buffer. To achieve this you need to create a loop, checking how much is left to read lie this:

```
while(buffer.remaining() > 0) channel.read(buffer);
```

In the powerful java stream API all this is handled automatically.

I suggest using a simple [BufferedReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) and then measure the performance. Then you can take a more informed decision on trying again with the NIO classes. You will be surprised by the performance of the stream based classes. This solution will also give you code that is easier to maintain and read.

Answer (score 1):

if you have `bytesRead%13!=0` then map a new buffer to `channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, (bytesRead/13)*13, capacity);` and don't process the last `bytesRead%13` of each buffer

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `MappedByteBuffer`, then you might as well map the entire file in one go.  Java and the OS VM system will read data from disk to memory *as required*.  It will not read the entire file into memory at once, unless it is really small.  Then you can focus on your code on merely access the range of bytes your are interested in for each loop/read.

Your more detailed, complex approach so far (and the corresponding answers here) are more suitable to a traditional [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html), in which you control explicitly what is read into memory from disk.